# How to use Mongo --authenticationDatabase in perl

Tags: mongodb, perl

This is how I connect to mongoDB in perl

```
my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(
    host     => 'badhost',
    port     => 37018,
    username => 'abc_user',
    password => 'abc_user',
    db_name  => 'cust_projectdb'
) or die "unable to connect to mongo\n";
```

when the connection string from shell is
`mongo  cust_projectdb --port 37018 -uabc_user -pabc_user --host badhost`

but how to connect when the connection string uses a different collection for authentication like this:

`mongo  cust_projectdb --port 37018 -uabc_user -pabc_user --host badhost --authenticationDatabase admin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `db_name` parameter sets the authentication database when you are connecting to the server, so you would want

```
db_name => 'admin'
```

to do the equivalent of your command line connection, although `admin` is the default here anyway so you can just omit it altogether

If you want to access the `cust_projectdb` database then you need to use `get_database` on the `MongoDB::MongoClient` object you just created to do that

```
my $db = $client->get_database('cust_projectdb')
```